the usage of staticAccountKeys in VersionedTransaction
this is the struct of MessageV0, but I'm very curious about the staticAccountKeys field. What is its purpose? I couldn't find any explanation for this field in Solana's cookbook (https://solanacookbook.com/guides/versioned-transactions.html#address-lookup-tables-lut). Additionally, in actual usage, this field is quite large, which could easily lead to my requests exceeding the maximum size limit.
export class MessageV0 {
    header: MessageHeader;
    staticAccountKeys: Array<PublicKey>;
    recentBlockhash: Blockhash;
    compiledInstructions: Array<MessageCompiledInstruction>;
    addressTableLookups: Array<MessageAddressTableLookup>;
    constructor(args: MessageV0Args);
    get version(): 0;
    get numAccountKeysFromLookups(): number;
    getAccountKeys(args?: GetAccountKeysArgs): MessageAccountKeys;
    isAccountSigner(index: number): boolean;
    isAccountWritable(index: number): boolean;
    resolveAddressTableLookups(addressLookupTableAccounts: AddressLookupTableAccount[]): AccountKeysFromLookups;
    static compile(args: CompileV0Args): MessageV0;
    serialize(): Uint8Array;
    private serializeInstructions;
    private serializeAddressTableLookups;
    static deserialize(serializedMessage: Uint8Array): MessageV0;
}

this is the data of VersionedTransaction, staticAccountKeys is really huge

meanwhile, I got this error Error: failed to simulate transaction: invalid transaction: Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly for sending trans if clear staticAccountKeys in MessageV0

The staticAccountKeys is an array of all the account addresses required by the instructions on the transaction (that are not part of an address lookup table).
The compiledInstructions reference the accounts listed in staticAccountKeys by index.

So, could we have some ways to merge static account keys into lookup table?
